# How to change the sharepoint Configuration on sqlserver namedInstance to default Instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint

I have installed sqlserver as namedinstance first .say(sqlnamed).later i have 
  installed sharepoint and configured named instance as database server for sharepoint 
  Now i have installed sqldefault instance.
  Now How to configure the sharepoint server to use default instance instead of 
  namedinstance.

What is the Procedure i hacve to follow to achieve this?what is the query i need
  to run??

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to re run the configuration Wizard to get it working . Refer to the [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/09/sql-server-error-fix-sharepoint-stop-working-after-changing-server-computer-name/) article which talks about the renaming of the SQL Server. But same steps applies to your case as well.